# Access data from Object in json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My json returns `below shown` set of array of objects and I need to access the data inside it. In the `console` this is what the response looks like
[image]

What i am trying to do is to access the object to get the `subcategoryid` and `subcategoryname` then display it inside a dropdown list. Here is my code for it

```
$.get('ajax-subcat?cat_id=' + cat_id, function(data)
          {
              console.log(data);

              $('#subcategory').empty();

              $.each(data, function(index, subcatObj)
              {
                alert(subcatObj);
                $('#subcategory').append('<option value="' + subcatObj.Object.subcategoryid +'">' + subcatObj.subcategoryname +'</option>');
              });

          });
```

The thing I don't know is how to access the data inside the object. Any ideas?

Comment: Just replace subcatObj.Object.subcategoryid with subcatObj.subcategoryid

Comment: hi @PrakashThete i tried it but did'nt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].subcategoryid);
}
```

Comment: hello why is it logging twice?

Comment: Hi, in what manner is it logging twice? Can you maybe provide me with an example from the logged output in the console then I can maybe tell you why?

Comment: hm for example i have `subcategoryid` 7,8,9 in the console it is being logged 3 times. i have this onchange and the `isTrigger` value is 3 maybe that causes the error

Comment: Okay that might be the issue, but I am not quite sure. The following reasons can cause the data to log more than once: 1. Multiple Objects with same value, 2. ;$.get' gets bound more than once, 3. The console.log  is called more than once. Maybe update your answer with an example of current output with the example I gave and your full code or function so we can determine what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a select element in markup:

```
<select id="mySelectElement"></select>
```

Try this to iterate the object and fill the combo box:

```
$.get('ajax-subcat?cat_id=' + cat_id, function(data) {
   // Get a reference to the target element
   var selectTarget = $('#mySelectElement');
   // Iterate over the response data
   for (var i in data) {
      // For every object in array, append a new option element
      selectTarget.append($('<option value="' + data[i].subcategoryid + '">' + data[i].subcategoryname + '</option>'));
   }
});
```

Comment: hi i did this but it was not able to populate the dropdown? any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose, you can use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library to get whole data corresponding to particular key in the form of array.

```
_.pluck(data, 'subCategoryid') // array of all values corresponding to 'subcategoryid'
```